# Number of Governance units allocated to Suitelets, Portlets and Custom Forms

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How many governance units are suitelets, portlets and custom forms allocated? Is it 1000?

My SuiteScript 2.0 PDF Reference document specifies how many units are allocated to map/reduce and scheduled scripts but not specifically how many suitelets and portlets are allotted.

PS: when I say 'Custom Forms' I mean a custom InventoryAdjustment form where I apply a script to handle PageInit and SaveRecord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SuiteScript Usage Limits are documented in the "SuiteScript General" section of the documentation

[SuiteCloud (Customization, Scripting, and Web Services) > SuiteScript > SuiteScript General > SuiteScript Governance Script Usage Unit Limits](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10481)

All script types mentioned in the question have 1000 units available.